# Make INVISIBLE View handle touches as ACTION_OUTSIDE

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I want to create transparent system overlay window, which has several round views:

[image]

Green view is `VISIBLE`, red one is `INVISIBLE`. The thing is that I need red view to pass touches to the underlying window, but by default it doesn't.

I tried setting visibility of red view to `GONE`, but then overall size of containing view changes. Since I need the containing view to be snapped to the right edge of the screen, this means that position of green view changes, and I don't want this.

**Is there any way to override default touch handling in `INVISIBLE` state?**

---

Here's an actual screenshot to make my question more clear:

[image]

Also, I had to override `dispatchTouchEvent()` to dispatch touch events correctly:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Circle target=null;
    int targetIndex=-1;
    for (int i=0; i<getChildCount(); i++) {
        Circle child=(Circle) getChildAt(i);
        if (child.viewMetrics.containsPoint(ev.getX(), ev.getY()) && (ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE || child.isVisible())) {
            target=child;
            targetIndex=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    onMotionEvent(ev, target, targetIndex);
    Log.d(">| CircularLayout", "action: "+ev.getAction()+", target: "+target);
    return target!=null && target.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is calculating two sets of view dimensions: **maximum possible** (size of the red area) and **current** (green area). When child view is hidden or shown I set `width` and `height` of window `LayoutParams` to current dimensions and then set difference between maximum and current dimensions to `y` and `x` parameters of `LayoutParams`.

For some reason applying modified `LayoutParams` triggers measure/layout pass twice (which in turn causes the view to "bounce"), but that seems to be the whole new story.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom view to do this. In such case you do not need any trickery related to visible invisible - it's you who decide what is your clickable area and also you who decies what area will alter the state (like is drawn as `pressed` on touch event). So your custom view should be of the size of desired area but in your `onDraw()` you shall only draw the change on that smaller inner area.

Here are basics on how to create custom views: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: Actually views are custom :) Clickable area is determined and drawn correctly. My problem is that I can't get touch events outside of it to be passed to windows under my overlay (as if their action was ACTION_OUTSIDE).

Comment: Maybe you always return `true` from your `onTouchEvent()`
?

Comment: Actually, I had to override `dispatchTouchEvent()`, but it returns `true` only if visible area is clicked.

Comment: Added more details to my question.