# How to get click event of a view under a view in android

Tags: android, layout, overlay, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

Since some days I'm figuring how I could delegate a click event to a view which sits below another. Important is that the overlay view still has to receive click events.

The situation is like this:

I have a RecyclerView with items. The RecyclerView takes full width with a padding on each side so the overscroll animation is spread nicely on the full width.
And I have a toolbar which lays under the RecyclerView (Extended Style). The toolbar has a menu item at the right top edge of the window.

Now I won't receive any click event on this menu item, because the RecyclerView is overlapping the item. But if I take the paddings in account the items of the RecyclerView are not overlapping the menu item. But still since the paddings are no margins the RecyclerView is invisibly overlapping the menu item. But I hate to change the paddings into margins, because then the overscroll animation is cut on both sides (left and right).

Do you have any suggestion on how I could either spread the overscroll animation to full width, or how I could delegate the click event through the paddings of my RecyclerView?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you find the solution please help m stuck since 10 days.

Comment: I know I'm late but I ended up, changing the whole layout. What you could do additionally is to override the touch events so the recycler doesn't respond anymore to the touch event. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520072/make-invisible-view-handle-touches-as-action-outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520072/make-invisible-view-handle-touches-as-action-outside). However this is rather complicated and I suggest to you to change your design so it works without that hardcore method.

Comment: See the below answer may be it will hlp someone else.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
  mRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            MotionEvent e = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
            mHeaderLayout.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
            e.recycle();
            return false;
        });
```